# Why doesn't my music bot play anything in a stage channel?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, youtube-dl

just forked a music bot from here:https://gist.github.com/vbe0201/ade9b80f2d3b64643d854938d40a0a2d

And I want to reproduce music in stage channel, so I changed the join command to make suppress False.

Here is the join code:

```
@commands.command(name="join", invoke_without_subcommand=True)
async def _join(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    destination = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_state.voice:
        await ctx.voice_state.voice.move_to(destination)
        return
    if ctx.author.voice.channel.type == discord.enums.ChannelType.stage_voice:
        ctx.voice_state.voice = await destination.connect()
        # await ctx.me.request_to_speak()
        await ctx.me.edit(suppress=False)
    else:
        ctx.voice_state.voice = await destination.connect()
```

And here is the play code:

```
    async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, search: str):
        if search.__contains__("?list="):
            if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
                await ctx.invoke(self._join)
            async with ctx.typing():
                playlist, playlistTitle = self._playlist(search)
                for _title, _link in playlist.items():
                    try:
                        source = await YTDLSource.create_source(
                            ctx, _link, loop=self.bot.loop
                        )
                    except YTDLError as e:
                        await ctx.send("リクエストの手続きにエラーが起きました：{}".format(str(e)))
                    else:
                        song = Song(source)
                        await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
            await ctx.send(
                f"**{playlistTitle}からの曲を`{playlist.__len__()}`件キューに追加されました**"
            )
        else:
            async with ctx.typing():
                try:
                    source = await YTDLSource.create_source(
                        ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop
                    )
                except YTDLError as e:
                    await ctx.send("リクエストの手続きにエラーが起きました：{}".format(str(e)))
                else:
                    song = Song(source)
                    if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
                        await ctx.invoke(self._join)
                    await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
                    await ctx.send("キューに追加されました {}".format(str(source)))
```

The bot be the speaker, but he doesn't play anything. When is a normal voice channel, he works fine.

When I request to speak instead of make suppress = False, it plays only one track, and doesn't play next tracks.

Someone have an idea of what is happening?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your 'play' command's code, as it might have some checks which prevent it from playing again; the `_join` command's code looks fine. See [ask], [help/on-topic] and [mcve].

Comment: The code is forked from the git link that I sent, so You can see the entire code from there (And I doesn't made big changes from there). But I will include in the question My version of the code c: